# Finding Closest Pair using Manhattan Distance

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to implement the Closest Pair algorithm with Manhattan distance. With Euclidean distance, it's working fine, but with Manhattan distance, it gives the wrong result. CLRS Exercise 33.4-3 asks us to replace Euclidean distance with Manhattan distance. They simply ask us to change one line, but it isn't what modification is needed in the below code.

```
lst = [(2,2),(4,2),(5,3)]

min_dist = float("inf")

for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(i + 1 , len(lst)):
        dist = abs(lst[i][0] - lst[j][0]) + abs(lst[i][1] - lst[j][1])
        if(dist < min_dist):
            min_dist = dist
            global minp1, minp2
            minp1 = lst[i]
            minp2 = lst[j]
```

Comment: Please explain what _wrong result_ you got and what you expected.

Comment: Coincidence? http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/47117/finding-closest-pair-using-manhattan-distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the outcome of programs with both distances are different.
Indeed, with the euclidian distance, the closest pair is `(4,2)-(5,3)` while with the Manhattan distance, both `(2,2)-(4,2)` and `(4,2)-(5,3)` are closest pairs. Given  your program, you only pick up the first one in the order of appearance, and the outcome is `(2,2)-(4,2)`. If your program would return all closest pairs, you would have seen `(4,2)-(5,3)`.

But generally speaking, there is no reason for the outcome of both programs to be the same. For example, in your example, change `(5,3)` to `(5,3.1)`. To have a concrete idea of how different both distances are, it may useful for you to plot the "unit circle" using for norms and you will see that the Manhattan circle is more square than round.